# Preview Problems for Toolbar in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-toolbar

I'm unable to view my toolbar or tab layout in android studio. I get the following errors.

```
The following classes could not be found:

-android.support.design.widget.Tablayout
-android.support.v4.viw.ViewPager
-android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
```

Inevitably what this means is I have to guess how any stylistic changes will look, or run the app for every change. Are there any fixes or workarounds for this? I know the toolbar and tab layout designs are fairly recent updates to the android library so I understand the issues.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the required libraries to your gradle file?

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.+' // for Toolbar
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0' // for TabLayout 
}
```

Comment: Yes the layouts run on devices and emulators just not on the design previews